# Reaching parameters of pulse generator on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

While trying to drive steper motor from s function I have to reach the parameters of pulse generator. What I have to do is adjust the period parameter of pulse generator in order to be able to adjust the stepper motor.However, I don't know how to reach them on simulink via either s-function or matlab function. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're not going to be able to change the block's period on a time step by time step basis.  You need to write a variable step S-Function that acts as a VCO for controlling the stepper motor.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question, but you can simply set the parameters from matlab, like this;

```
set_param('test_project/Pulse Generator','Period','0.1');
```

or

```
set_param('test_project/Pulse Generator','Period','a_variable');
```

the same for other parameters;

```
set_param('test_project/Pulse Generator','Amplitude','an_other_var*2*pi');
set_param('test_project/Pulse Generator','Amplitude','100');
set_param('test_project/Pulse Generator','Pulse Width','eps');
```

this could be done in a for loop for example;

```
for j=1:1:10
    set_param('test_project/Pulse Generator','Period','j*2*pi');
    % do other things here...
end
```

You can do it from s-function too, dedicate an output in matlab workspace and then do something similar to those codes above.

hope I understood your point.

Comment: The OP needs a variable frequency pulse generator where the next rise/fall of the pulse is controlled based on what is happening at this time step if the simulation.  Using `set_param` as you've outlines won't do that correctly while the simulation is running.

Comment: Is it possible in this case to use a `Unit delay`  block, since the simulation is discrete time based? Putting `unit delay`  block on output of s-function or whatever matlab or simulink block that calculates based on `result(k-1)` and then using `set_param` determines the `period(k)`. I'll update my answer with blocks.

Comment: You can't change the sample time of a typical block (such as the Unit Delay) during simulation.  Only block's that have been specifically written to allow VariableSampleTime, like a variable step S-Function, allow this.